# Use of new keyword for objects vs. list of object

Tags: vb.net, list, collections

I’m trying to understand the use of the `NEW` keyword when used with an object vs. a list of objects.

**EXAMPLE A:**

This prints out “Class value = 10” 10 times.

```
Public Class TestClass
    Private _testInt As Integer
    Property TestInt As Integer
        Get
            Return _testInt
        End Get
        Set(value As Integer)
            _testInt = value
        End Set
    End Property
End Class

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim test As New List(Of TestClass)
        Dim localTest = New TestClass
        For i As Integer = 0 To 10
            localTest.TestInt = i
            test.Add(localTest)
        Next
        For i As Integer = 0 To 10
            Console.WriteLine("Class value = " & test(i).TestInt.ToString)
        Next
    End Sub
```

**EXAMPLE B:**

If I move the declaration of `localTest` to inside the loop, it will print out “Class value = 1 to 10”.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim test As New List(Of TestClass)
    For i As Integer = 0 To 10
        Dim localTest = New TestClass
        localTest.TestInt = i
        test.Add(localTest)
    Next
    For i As Integer = 0 To 10
        Console.WriteLine("Class value = " & test(i).TestInt.ToString)
    Next
End Sub
```

It seems to me that `localTest` is acting like an instance of an object while `test` acts like a list of pointers to an object.

**Q1.** Is `localTest` an instance of an object or a pointer to an object?

**Q2.** Is `test` multiple instances of objects or a list of pointers to objects?  If it is **not** a list of pointers, why does example A print out “Class value = 10” 10 times?

**Q3.** Can you explain why the behavior is this way and what the `New` keyword means when working with objects vs. collections or lists of objects?

Any additional insight would be great.  Thank you.

**EDIT:**

I've marked an answer as accepted below, primarily because it contained a link to a webpage that was really useful.  On the webpage it says the following which helped me understand what was happening:

> You can assign either a reference type or a value type to a variable
>   of the Object data type. An Object variable always holds a pointer to
>   the data, never the data itself. However, if you assign a value type
>   to an Object variable, it behaves as if it holds its own data.

Comment: The quote from the MSDN article that you added in your edit is referring to what is known as [boxing](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yz2be5wk.aspx).  In this case, though, you weren't actually doing anything in your example code which used boxing, so I'm not exactly sure why you think that was the most pertinent part of the article.  I'm concerned that you may still not fully grasp the concept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TestClass` is declared as a `Class`.  That means it is a [reference type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t63sy5hs.aspx).  Since it is a reference type, that means that all variables of that type will act as pointers.  If you want it to not act as a pointer, you need to declare it as a `Structure` (a value type).

In some other languages, the same type of value can be stored directly by the variable or as a pointer (e.g. `int x;` vs `int *x;` in C).  In .NET languages, however, that decision is determined globally by the type rather than by the variable.

Lists of reference types are lists of pointers.  Lists of value types store copies of the actual values.

Comment: Thanks.  The link was useful.  See my question EDIT.

Comment: Yes, I thought of mentioning [boxing](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yz2be5wk.aspx) in my answer, but I didn't want to go too far and confuse you even more.